# What is the meaning of 'to' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

When the pasta is done **to your liking**, drain the water.

Done mean =prepared i think, plz explain me?

'To' mean in this context =?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Prepared according to the way you like it.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/done#Adjective): "done"

> 3. (of food) Ready, fully cooked.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Preposition): "to"

> 12. according to
>     *Our holiday did not go to plan*